# INotifyPropertyChanged on a derived class

Tags: c#, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I've got a class which is also a table on a sqlite database on a Windows Phone 8 project.

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private int _itemID;
   private string _name;

   [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
   public string ItemID
   {
       get { return _barcode; }
       set 
       { 
           if (value != _itemID)
           {
              _itemID = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }
   }

   [MaxLength(100)]
   public string Name
   {
       get { return _name; }
       set 
       { 
           if (value != _name)
           {
              _name = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }
   }

}
```

And another class I use in my View which derives from Item.

```
public class SubItem : Item, INotifyPropertyChange
{
    public class SubItem() {}

    public class SubItem(Item item)
    {
        this.ItemID = item.ItemID;
        this.Name = item.Name;
    }


 // Other properties implementing INPC
...
}
```

Now when the derived items are loaded my View doesn't seem to get updated. How does change notification work on derived classes?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to specify the interface in the derived class if the base class implements it.

Comment: Yeah Bort, that was a typo.

Comment: nothing wrong with specifying it there though. Especially when you are wanting to depend on behaviour from it like this - saves a lot of f12'ing sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are firing the events in the constructor ... ie nothing will of hooked up to the events yet.

also you cant call events from the inherited class like this iirc.